# How to merge two JavaScripts as one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these two JavaScripts. One is for the preloader and the other ones are for mail chimp subscribe form.
In my MailChimp account, I've set the form to appear after 20seconds but my problem is, it loads faster than my webpage and sometimes it would appear before my preloader is gone. It's really not what I want.
Please is it possible to have the mailchimp show only when the entire page is done loading?
I'm still new to JavaScript and jquery and I have no idea on how to do this. Please help. Below are the scripts. Thanks for helping.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var clPreloader = function() {

        $("html").addClass('cl-preload');

        $WIN.on('load', function() {

            //force page scroll position to top at page refresh
            // $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'normal');

            // will first fade out the loading animation 
            $("#loader").fadeOut("slow", function() {
                // will fade out the whole DIV that covers the website.
                $("#preloader").delay(300).fadeOut("slow");
            }); 

            // for hero content animations 
            $("html").removeClass('cl-preload');
            $("html").addClass('cl-loaded');

        });
    };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/unique-methods/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">window.dojoRequire(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us19.list-manage.com","uuid":"a16126f77b33bc58d8eef3c50","lid":"a69743e135","uniqueMethods":true}) })</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this webpage will help you with your problem
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload
The `onload` function in javascript allows you to execute code when the page has been loaded.

Otherwise you could add a function call to the next script you want to execute, after the first one has finished executing.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I've done it. I added  <script type=text/JavaScript> Function Load(){window.dojoRequire(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us19.list-manage.com","uuid":"a16126f77b33bc58d8eef3c50","lid":"a69743e135","uniqueMethods":true}) }) }<script>.

Answer (score 0):

try somthing like this after animation end

```
var linkafterpreload = "link 1";

window.addEventListener("load", _ => {
    var newscript = document.createElement("script");
    newscript.src = linkafterpreload ;
    document.body.appendChild("newscript")
})
```